# Vim: How to perform last action on the entire document?

Tags: vim

I've just performed the following command :

```
:s/^.*foo/bar/
```

And I was wondering if there is a shortcut to have this action immediately performed on the entire document at once.

TBN : I already know you can use the '%' entry, like that :

```
:%s/^.*foo/bar/
```

or simply hit '.' or '@:' on each document line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want to re-do the `:s` command on whole buffer (`%`), you could just in Normal mode press:

```
g&
```

for general commands, press:

```
:%<c-r>:<cr>
```

`<c-r>` is <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd>

`<cr>` is <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: +1. Also probably good to look into `:h q:` if digging through command history becomes a common occurrence.